# I can't get SimpleMappingExceptionResolver work the way I want

Tags: exception, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3 and I tried to add exception mapping this way:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <map>
                <entry key="it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.AcciseAuthException" value="/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp" />              
            </map>
        </property>     
    </bean>
```

of course jsp(s) are NOT in WEB-INF but in a folder in the root called `jsp`. What I get is my custom page for 404 handling, that I configured in web.xml. What's wrong?

Here is Spring log with DEBUG enabled:

```
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,451 CET] [DEBUG] [HandlerMethodInvoker] [invokeHandlerMethod:173] - Invoking request handler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.MainController.prodottiList(int,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.Integer,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws java.lang.Exception
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,452 CET] [DEBUG] [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver] [resolveException:132] - Resolving exception from handler [it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.MainController@1876a6d]: it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.AcciseAuthException
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,454 CET] [DEBUG] [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver] [findMatchingViewName:202] - Resolving to view '/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp' for exception of type [it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.AcciseAuthException], based on exception mapping [it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.AcciseAuthException]
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,454 CET] [DEBUG] [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver] [getModelAndView:294] - Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,458 CET] [DEBUG] [DispatcherServlet] [processHandlerException:1001] - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name '/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp'; model is {exception=it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.AcciseAuthException}
it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.AcciseAuthException
    at it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.ApplicationUserStatus.checkIfUserPrivilegeBelowOrEqual(ApplicationUserStatus.java:162)
    at it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.MainController.prodottiList(MainController.java:401)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,464 CET] [DEBUG] [DefaultListableBeanFactory] [invokeInitMethods:1461] - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name '/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp'
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,465 CET] [DEBUG] [DefaultListableBeanFactory] [doGetBean:242] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,465 CET] [DEBUG] [DispatcherServlet] [render:1045] - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name '/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp'; URL [/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,466 CET] [DEBUG] [JstlView] [exposeModelAsRequestAttributes:328] - Added model object 'exception' of type [it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.AcciseAuthException] to request in view with name '/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp'
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,466 CET] [DEBUG] [JstlView] [renderMergedOutputModel:236] - Forwarding to resource [/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp] in InternalResourceView '/jsp/errorUserPage.jsp'
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,467 CET] [DEBUG] [OpenSessionInViewInterceptor] [afterCompletion:212] - Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewInterceptor
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,468 CET] [DEBUG] [SessionFactoryUtils] [closeSession:789] - Closing Hibernate Session
[08 mar 2011 15:20:11,468 CET] [DEBUG] [DispatcherServlet] [processRequest:674] - Successfully completed request
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm adding this for who'll see this question in the future. This configuration is OK, the JSP was just wrong. Thanks anyway to the answer that proposes a better method to handle this is Spring 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to have .jsp in the exception value? How are your controllers and view resolvers  etc set up? Do they append a .jsp to the value before resolving paths etc?

Do you need to have the exception mapping in xml? Could the @ExceptionHandler annotation fullfill your expectations?

Here is a nice example of xml based spring exception resolvers (although spring 2.5 based): http://developingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/03/09/handling-exceptions-in-spring-mvc-part-2/

Do note if you go the annotation way that the annotations methods needs to be within the same controller class (or abstract class). I wrote a small example of this: http://blog.flurdy.com/2010/07/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-needs-to-be.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that you can handle exceptions with annotations... Probably I should read Spring docs more carefully. Anyway, is it just my impression, or Spring 3 docs suck? I mean they don't give much details or examples, I have to google for hours to understand why certain things don't work....

Comment: Yes their docs do leave out some details. The api docs, and their sample apps do fill in some of the gaps, but google and stack overflow is a necessary tool :)